# Can I get advice for hunting down unwanted JavaScript on a Magento page?

Tags: javascript, magento

I have a product page on a Magento 1.7 installation that has a product with tiered pricing. It should say buy 4 and save 13%, which it does for a split second before the value of 13% is overwritten by 100% (which is incorrect). I can only assume that there is some buggy JavaScript on the page that is causing this, but I have no idea how to find it. Can somebody please give me some advice on how to find and fix this bug please?

Here is the page: http://makethemostof.co.uk/lace-print-cushions

Comment: Did you try disabling Javascript in your browser, and reloading the page? I'd do that, to make sure you're not debugging a non-bug.

Comment: rule of a dumb :) disable one by one and locate the file

Comment: I have outlined a fix for this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16022796/159341

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looked at the HTML element in the Chrome Inspector: `class="benefit"`.

Searched ".benefit" in the Resources tab, 1 match, in the loupe.js file.

Went to the Scripts tab, loupe.js file, prettify the code, search ".benefit".

```
       $$('.benefit').each(function(el) {
            var parsePrice = function(html) {
                return parseFloat(/\d+\.?\d*/.exec(html));
            };
            var container = $(this.containers[3]) ? this.containers[3] : this.containers[0];
            var price = parsePrice($(container).innerHTML);
            var tierPrice = $$('.price.tier-' + i);
            tierPrice = tierPrice.length ? parseInt(tierPrice[0].innerHTML, 10) : 0;
            var $percent = Selector.findChildElements(el, ['.percent.tier-' + i]);
            $percent.each(function(el) {
                el.innerHTML = Math.ceil(100 - ((100 / price) * tierPrice));
            });
        }, this);
```

Found the script in less than a minute thanks to Chrome Inspector.

Now, here is the culprit:

```
el.innerHTML = Math.ceil(100 - ((100 / price) * tierPrice));
```

It's an easy math calculation. I don't know what `tierPrice` is, but I'm sure you can find out the correct calculation for your business (`Math.ceil` rounds up the number).

Comment: Doesn't Math.ceil round up, not down?

Comment: No problem.  Good job hunting down the problem.

Comment: more on "teaching how to fish" - this post by Majd Taby is brilliant - [http://jtaby.com/2012/04/23/modern-web-development-part-1.html](http://jtaby.com/2012/04/23/modern-web-development-part-1.html)

Comment: Thanks so much... you've taught me several things that I didn't know about the chrome inspector all at once - in particular the 'prettify' tool. I'm still unfortunately totally lost as to why I'm not getting the correct value but at least I now know where to start looking and how to use the inspector to keep on looking. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's

```
for (var i > 0; i < this.tierPrices.length; i++) {
```

If you replace it for 1 it will just calculate the correct Savings % for the first tier price not for the others after that, they wil still be set to 100%.

While he needs to calculate it for all tierprices so if `i` is greater then 0 he needs to calculate the correct tier % otherwise it's the same price as the product price or equal to 0 or 100%

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested specifically in the bug in Magento 1.7 where tier price savings are always displayed as 100% this is the fix:

In js/varien/product.js change the following on line 748:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.tierPrices.length; i++) {
```

with

```
for (var i > 1; i < this.tierPrices.length; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is great post on trying to get to the bottom of what is causing the issue, I found that the solutions on the page just prevent the code from running, they don't actually solve the problem. I have posted a solution to this problem here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022796/159341