# Magento tier prices - class declaration for tier price in BUY x for Y - javascript

Tags: javascript, magento

There is an outstanding bug in 1.6+ versions of Magento where the % savings for tier prices defaults to 100% when an option is selected. Other contributors have suggested changing product.js around line 747 from

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.tierPrices.length; i++) {
```

to be

```
for (var i = 0; i > this.tierPrices.length; i++) {
```

This resolves the issue with % savings but that code block is never executed. I am by no means a Javascript expert but this block appears to be updating the tier price and % savings when options are selected. I wanted to find the root of the issue, rather than 'commenting it out'.

From my debugging in Firebug I noticed that the classes for tier price is wrong in product.js and therefore, a tier price of 0 is retrieved, which accounts for why % savings is always 100%. 
Firebug shows the price as

```
class="tier-prices product-pricing">   
        Buy 10 for  
        <span class="price">$40.00</span>
```

whereas product.js is attempting to retrieve the objects using

```
$$('.price.tier-' + i).each(function (el) {
```

If you change the above to

```
$$('.tier-prices .price).each(function (el) {
```

the tier price is retrieved, but for more than one tier price on a product, there is no way to refer to them individually. The class "price" above does not have a unique identifier or iterative number declared.

Where is class="price" declared for the tier price? In the code of tierprices.phtml it looks like this

```
<?php echo $this->__('Buy %1$s for %2$s each', $_price['price_qty'], $_price['formated_price'])?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just spent some time on this as it was really starting to bug me after I upgraded a customer's Magento site to 1.7.0.2.

There are two parts to this, I'm going to state the locations and the fixes, but these will not be upgrade proof (for that you will want to create copies of the files and put them in your theme specific folders, although I'm not sure if it's possible with the JS file in question).

**1) View Fix**

In the file `/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml`

you need to replace lines `32-34`

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

with the following code:

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_tierPrices = array();

foreach($this->getTierPrices() as $index => $info) {
    $_tierPrices[$index] = $info;
    $_tierPrices[$index]['formated_price'] = str_replace('class="price"', 'class="price tier-'.$index.'"', $info['formated_price']);
    $_tierPrices[$index]['formated_price_incl_tax'] = str_replace('class="price"', 'class="price tier-'.$index.' tier-'.$index.'-incl-tax"', $info['formated_price_incl_tax']);
}
$_finalPriceInclTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice(), true);
```

This fixes the issue with the class not being rendered correctly as you had already figured out. [Here is where I found this code](http://www.integer-net.de/magento-bug-individuelle-optionen-und-staffelpreise-100-prozent-ersparnis/) - although it didn't fix all the issues, hence the JS changes.

**2) JS fix**

in the file `js/Varien/product.js` you need to replace lines `757-769`:

```
$$('.benefit').each(function (el) {
    var parsePrice = function (html) {
        return parseFloat(/\d+\.?\d*/.exec(html));
    };
    var container = $(this.containers[3]) ? this.containers[3] : this.containers[0];
    var price = parsePrice($(container).innerHTML);
    var tierPrice = $$('.price.tier-' + i);
    tierPrice = tierPrice.length ? parseInt(tierPrice[0].innerHTML, 10) : 0;
    var $percent = Selector.findChildElements(el, ['.percent.tier-' + i]);
    $percent.each(function (el) {
        el.innerHTML = Math.ceil(100 - ((100 / price) * tierPrice));
    });
}, this);
```

With this:

```
//
// Code fixed to prevent the redundant inner loop and to use actual tiered pricing in calculation
// It also takes the optional price variants into consideration (eg: +£2 for a blue tshirt)
// Note: I've made this comment deliberately large, to keep the line numbers in sync
//
var parsePrice = function (html) {
    return parseFloat(/\d+\.?\d*/.exec(html));
};
var container = $(this.containers[3]) ? this.containers[3] : this.containers[0];
var price = parsePrice($(container).innerHTML);
$$('.percent.tier-' + i).each(function (el) {
    el.innerHTML = Math.ceil(100 - ((100 / price) * (this.tierPrices[i] + parseFloat(optionPrices))));
}, this);
```

I hope this saves at least one person a few hours of their life.

T

Comment: Thank you, worked great. Don't forget if you have a custom product.js in your skin you should modify it there.

Answer (score 0):

The part `class="price"` is the result from `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency::formatPrecision()` and executed when `$this->formatPrice()` or in deeper model layers the price is formatted 
with `Mage::helper('core')->formatPrice();`

You could add the unique identifier by extending (and rewriting) the `Mage_Directory_Model_Currency` but be aware that `formatPrecision` is used everywhere. So you could write your own helper/model logic for formatting tier prices.