# Magento: Price tier returns NAN

Tags: html, css, magento

I'm using Magento 1.9.0 and I have a problem with Price Tiers. I configured the price tier the correct way but it's displaying in the front end: Not a Number (see screenshot).

[image]

The strange thing is that if I take a look at the source code everything looks fine.

[image]

Comment: I think a JavaScript function is used to change the price which returns `NaN` (not a number)

Comment: thanks for the hint, I will take a look at the javascript files which are executed.

Comment: I finally found the answer in another Stackoverflow post: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504056/magento-tier-prices-class-declaration-for-tier-price-in-buy-x-for-y-javascri